# Instantiate multiple identical objects

Tags: java, queue

I am having an wierd issue when instantiating multiple objects of the same type.

I am trying to parse a newly created object into a `LinkedList queue`. So the thing that goes wrong is, it is supposed to parse the first object `tempBoardDirection` into the queue in the first if statement, and afterwards parse the second object `tempBoardDirectionLeft` into the queue.

The part where it goes wrong is that it looks more like it is just changing my `tempBoard` object, because when I print the field out I am changing it it always the same in thoose 3 objects.

Where am I making the error since they are referring to each other?

I tried to look at the `tempBoard.robots[0]`, both before first if statement, after it and after second if statement and this was the data:

- before first if statement - `java.awt.Point[x=0,y=1]`
- After first if statement - `java.awt.Point[x=0,y=4]`
- After second if statmenet - `java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]`

This shouldn't be changed from `java.awt.Point[x=0,y=1]`, as I am creating new objects and editing their attributes, not `tempBoard`attributes.

This is a snippet of the function that should explain where it goes wrong:

```
while(!q.isEmpty()){
                    Board tempBoard = q.poll();
    ​
                    if(tempBoard.isGoal())
                        return tempBoard.moves;
    ​
                    Endpoints endpoint = tempBoard.possibleEndpointsForRobot(0);
                    System.out.println(tempBoard.robots[0]);
    ​
                    if(!visited[endpoint.right.x][endpoint.right.y]){
                        Board tempBoardDirection = new Board(tempBoard.board, tempBoard.robots, tempBoard.goal);
                        tempBoardDirection.moves = tempBoard.moves;
                        tempBoardDirection.moveRobot(0,Direction.Right);
                        visited[endpoint.right.x][endpoint.right.y] = true;
                        q.add(tempBoardDirection);
                        System.out.println("right: "+tempBoardDirection.robots[0]);
                    }
    ​
                    if(!visited[endpoint.left.x][endpoint.left.y]){
                        Board tempBoardDirectionLeft = new Board(tempBoard.board, tempBoard.robots, tempBoard.goal);
                        tempBoardDirectionLeft.moves = tempBoard.moves;
                        tempBoardDirectionLeft.moveRobot(0,Direction.Left);
                        visited[endpoint.left.x][endpoint.left.y] = true;
                        q.add(tempBoardDirectionLeft);
                        System.out.println("Left: "+tempBoardDirectionLeft.robots[0]);
                    }
    ​
```

Here is the whole function on where it fails:

```
public String computeSolution() throws Exception {
            Queue<Board> q = new LinkedList<>();
​
            q.add(this.board);
            this.visited[this.board.robots[0].x][this.board.robots[0].y] = true;
​
            int i = 0;
​
            while(!q.isEmpty()){
                Board tempBoard = q.poll();
​
                if(tempBoard.isGoal())
                    return tempBoard.moves;
​
                Endpoints endpoint = tempBoard.possibleEndpointsForRobot(0);
                System.out.println(tempBoard.robots[0]);
​
                if(!visited[endpoint.right.x][endpoint.right.y]){
                    Board tempBoardDirection = new Board(tempBoard.board, tempBoard.robots, tempBoard.goal);
                    tempBoardDirection.moves = tempBoard.moves;
                    tempBoardDirection.moveRobot(0,Direction.Right);
                    visited[endpoint.right.x][endpoint.right.y] = true;
                    q.add(tempBoardDirection);
                    System.out.println("right: "+tempBoardDirection.robots[0]);
                }
​
                if(!visited[endpoint.left.x][endpoint.left.y]){
                    Board tempBoardDirectionLeft = new Board(tempBoard.board, tempBoard.robots, tempBoard.goal);
                    tempBoardDirectionLeft.moves = tempBoard.moves;
                    tempBoardDirectionLeft.moveRobot(0,Direction.Left);
                    visited[endpoint.left.x][endpoint.left.y] = true;
                    q.add(tempBoardDirectionLeft);
                    System.out.println("Left: "+tempBoardDirectionLeft.robots[0]);
                }
​
                if(!visited[endpoint.up.x][endpoint.up.y]){
                    System.out.println("works up");
                    Board tempBoardDirection = new Board(tempBoard.board, tempBoard.robots, tempBoard.goal);
                    tempBoardDirection.moves = tempBoard.moves;
                    tempBoardDirection.moveRobot(0,Direction.Up);
                    visited[endpoint.up.x][endpoint.up.y] = true;
                    q.add(tempBoardDirection);
                }
​
                if(!visited[endpoint.down.x][endpoint.down.y]){
                    System.out.println("works down");
                    Board tempBoardDirection = new Board(tempBoard.board, tempBoard.robots, tempBoard.goal);
                    tempBoardDirection.moves = tempBoard.moves;
                    tempBoardDirection.moveRobot(0,Direction.Down);
                    visited[endpoint.down.x][endpoint.down.y] = true;
                    q.add(tempBoardDirection);
                }
                //System.out.println(tempBoard.moves);
                i++;
            }
​
            System.out.println("num of loops: "+i);
            throw new Exception("no solution");
        }
```

UPDATE 1:

This is the Board class, as requested that I should place in here too.

```
public class Board {
    public static final char GOAL_CHAR = 'G';
    public static final char WALL_CHAR = '#';
    public static final char EMPTY_CHAR = ' ';
​
    public char[][] board;
    public int size;
    public Point[] robots;
    public Point goal;
    public String moves = "";
    public boolean[][] visited;
​
    public Board(char[][] board, Point[] robots, Point goal) {
        this.board = board;
        this.size = board.length;
        this.robots = robots;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.visited = new boolean[this.size][this.size];
    }
​
​
    public Integer getCurrentRobotFromQueue(Queue q) {
        return IntStream.range(0, robots.length).filter(i -> q.element().equals(robots[i])).findFirst().getAsInt();
    }
​
    public boolean isGoal() {
        return this.robots[0].equals(this.goal);
    }
​
    public Endpoints possibleEndpointsForRobot(int robot) {
        assert robot < robots.length;
​
        Point up = pointAfterMovingRobot(robot, Direction.Up);
        Point down = pointAfterMovingRobot(robot, Direction.Down);
        Point left = pointAfterMovingRobot(robot, Direction.Left);
        Point right = pointAfterMovingRobot(robot, Direction.Right);
​
        return new Endpoints(up, down, left, right);
    }
​
    public Point pointAfterMovingRobot(int robot, Direction m) {
        assert robot < robots.length;
​
        Point pos = new Point(robots[robot]);
        int drow = 0, dcol = 0;
​
        if (m == Direction.Up) {
            drow = -1;
        } else if (m == Direction.Down) {
            drow = 1;
        }
​
        if (m == Direction.Left) {
            dcol = -1;
        } else if (m == Direction.Right) {
            dcol = 1;
        }
​
        while (withinBoard(pos.x+drow, pos.y+dcol) &&
                (board[pos.x+drow][pos.y+dcol] == EMPTY_CHAR
                        || board[pos.x+drow][pos.y+dcol] == GOAL_CHAR)) {
            pos.translate(drow, dcol);
        }
​
        return pos;
    }
​
    public void moveRobot(int robot, Direction d) {
        assert robot < robots.length;
​
        Point from = robots[robot];
        Point to = pointAfterMovingRobot(robot, d);
        board[from.x][from.y] = EMPTY_CHAR;
        robots[robot] = to;
        board[to.x][to.y] = (char) ('0' + robot);
​
        //add move to moves.
​
        this.moves += robot+d.toString()+", ";
    }
​
    private boolean withinBoard(int x, int y) {
        return x >= 0 && x < size && y >= 0 && y < size;
    }
​
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size * size);
​
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            sb.append(board[i]);
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
​
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was that I needed to create a copy of the information before I create a new instance of the object.

The way I solved it was by making an new superclass and do it like this:

```
public Board(Board tempBoard){
    this.board = new char[tempBoard.board.length][tempBoard.board.length];
    this.robots = new  Point[tempBoard.robots.length];
    System.arraycopy( tempBoard.board, 0, board, 0, tempBoard.board.length );
    System.arraycopy( tempBoard.robots, 0, robots, 0, tempBoard.robots.length );
    this.size = tempBoard.size;
    this.goal = tempBoard.goal;
    this.moves = tempBoard.moves;
}
```